# LetsEncrypt : Intermediate certificate for LetsEncrypt

Tags: java, ssl, lets-encrypt, etherpad

We are currently using LetsEncrypt SSL certificates and it's working good. After some modifications we are able to pull it into Tomcat and Apache web server as well.

Currently, we want to add LetsEncrypt certificate to Etherpad, where it demands `intermediate CA` files. How can I get those out of the 4 certificate files provided by LetsEncrypt. Thank you..

LetsEncrypt SSL settings :

```
 "ssl" : {
            "key"  : "/path-to-your/epl-server.key",
            "cert" : "/path-to-your/epl-server.crt",
            "ca": ["/path-to-your/epl-intermediate-cert1.crt", "/path-to-your/epl-intermediate-cert2.crt"]
          },
```

In the above configuration I presume Key is the `privkey.pem` converted to .key file and .crt is `cert.pem` converted to cert.crt. What goes in the CA?

Thank you.

*Update*

Settings :

```
 "ssl" : {
            "key"  : "/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.project_name.de-0001/private.key",
            "cert" : "/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.project_name.de-0001/cert.crt",
            "ca": "/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.project_name.de-0001/root.crt"
          },
```

Error log when trying keys :

```
[2016-11-04 13:25:15.612] [INFO] console - Report bugs at https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite/issues
[2016-11-04 13:25:15.612] [INFO] console - Your Etherpad version is 1.6.0 (7dd934f)
[2016-11-04 13:25:15.613] [INFO] console - SSL -- enabled
[2016-11-04 13:25:15.613] [INFO] console - SSL -- server key file: /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.project_name.de-0001/private.key
[2016-11-04 13:25:15.614] [INFO] console - SSL -- Certificate Authority's certificate file: /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.project_name.de-0001/cert.crt
[2016-11-04 13:25:15.615] [ERROR] console - Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
```

Comment: Just [download them](https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/). The chain of trust for Lets Encrypt is rather complicated, you shouldn't need all of them.

Comment: @BoristheSpider : I downloaded ISRG Root X1, and presume its cert1.crt. I will try out first. Thank you.

Comment: @BoristheSpider : I tried the certificate file you suggested, I am getting an error for that. Can you please check the updated main post. Thanks.

Comment: If you remove the `ca` line temporarily, do you continue to see this error?

Comment: @AnandBhat : That worked. Thanks man. You can post it as an answer for me to accept. Thank you. :-)

Comment: Not having intermediate certificates in the `ca` option can cause some browsers to present an error. I suggest using a site such as https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html to check if you are sending the correct certificate chain and https://whatsmychaincert.com/ to download the correct chain for you site. Lastly, the `ca` option may need to be specified as a singleton array and not as a string (if I'm reading https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite/blob/7ecf240d9e46ac41259100bf83242ca7b8fc205b/src/node/hooks/express.js#L49 correctly)

Answer (score 1):

There should be a file called `chain.pem` in the same directory as `cert.pem`, this contains the certificate chain up to the root CA (for my cert it's only one certificate, but this may change in the future) and should be what you're asking for.

```
$ ls live/my.domain.com/
cert.pem  chain.pem  fullchain.pem  privkey.pem
```

I'm not familiar with Etherpad, but my guess is that you should configure it like this:

```
 "ssl" : {
            "key"  : "/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.project_name.de-0001/private.key",
            "cert" : "/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.project_name.de-0001/cert.pem",
            "ca": "/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.project_name.de-0001/chain.pem"
          },
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me how I should fill it up, as I tried one configuration and it didn't work. I have added more information to the main post. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, but I am still getting an error on cert.pem. Same error. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm  afraid I can't really help you with that since I'm not familiar with Etherpad. All I can tell you is that you seem to have the correct certificates on hand. Does it work without SSL?

Comment: Yes, without SSL is no problem. We are trying to configure SSL for it. Thank you.. :-)

Comment: Well, the error message in your post looks like something is pointing to a directory instead of a file to me. But I can't really contribute with more than that, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Since you should not run etherpad as root but letsencrypt might be used as root you first need the user running the instance of etherpad have read access to the certificates. Since my etherpad user has no access to letsencrypt
I copied && chown them to another directory a.e. /opt/certs/ where my etherpad user has access. This could be done by a cronjob when checking for expiring letsencrypt certificates.

Then in settings.json you need to add both chain.pem and fullchain.pem using

`"ca":["path to chain.pem", "path to fullchain.pem"]`

The part in settings.json would look like this:

```
"ssl" : {
            "key"  : "/opt/certs/privkey.pem",
            "cert" : "/opt/certs/cert.pem",
            "ca": ["/opt/certs/chain.pem", "/opt/certs/fullchain.pem"]
          },
```

It could be possible that the fullchain.pem is missing the root ca.
During the letsencrypt process, only the chain.pem is added without the root CA. Then you must merge the IdenTrust root Certificate after the chain.pem. The fullchain.pem should have them but sometimes it looks like it is missing the 'last' in the chain:

https://www.identrust.com/certificates/trustid/root-download-x3.html
worked for me.

fullchain.pem would look like this

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
 your chain.pem
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
 the intermediate / root ca https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```